# Merge a dict in Python using 1 dict as base

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am looking for feedback on my Python code. I am trying to merge two dictionaries. One of the dictionaries controls the structure and the default values, the second dictionary will overwrite the default values when applicable.

Please note that I am looking for the following behaviour:

- keys only present in the other dict should **not** be added
- nested dicts should be taken into account

I wrote this simple function:

```
def merge_dicts(base_dict, other_dict):
    """ Merge two dicts

    Ensure that the base_dict remains as is and overwrite info from other_dict
    """
    out_dict = dict()
    for key, value in base_dict.items():
        if key not in other_dict:
            # simply use the base
            nvalue = value
        elif isinstance(other_dict[key], type(value)):
            if isinstance(value, type({})):
                # a new dict myst be recursively merged
                nvalue = merge_dicts(value, other_dict[key])
            else:
                # use the others' value
                nvalue = other_dict[key]
        else:
            # error due to difference of type
            raise TypeError('The type of key {} should be {} (currently is {})'.format(
                key,
                type(value),
                type(other_dict[key]))
            )
        out_dict[key] = nvalue
    return out_dict
```

I am sure this can be done more beautifully/pythonic.

Comment: The values of `other_dict` will not be added if the corresponding keys are not in `base_dict`. Is this wanted behavior?

Comment: So keys in `other_dict` that are not in `base_dict` should be ignored, right?

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, at least not of those questions; here nested `dict`s must be taken into account.

Comment: Yes, the additional keys should not be added. That is wanted behaviour.

Comment: Yes, nested dicts must be taken into account indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pythonicness" is a hard measure to assess, but here is my take on it:

```
def merge_dicts(base_dict, other_dict):
    """ Merge two dicts

    Ensure that the base_dict remains as is and overwrite info from other_dict
    """
    if other_dict is None:
        return base_dict
    t = type(base_dict)
    if type(other_dict) != t:
        raise TypeError("Mismatching types: {} and {}."
                        .format(t, type(other_dict)))
    if not issubclass(t, dict):
        return other_dict
    return {k: merge_dicts(v, other_dict.get(k)) for k, v in base_dict.items()}
```

Example:

```
merge_dicts({"a":2, "b":{"b1": 5, "b2": 7}}, {"b": {"b1": 9}})
>>> {'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 9, 'b2': 7}}
```

Comment: A good catch here is the "if other_dict is None", but why do you not use: "if not other_dict"?

Comment: @user1934514 To be honest I'm making the assumption that `other_dict` will never contain `None`, which I'm not sure if is good for your case. However, I guess `0`, `False`, `""` or `[]` are too valid values, so I avoid discarding them `is None` instead of just checking its "falsy" value (the `None` values are expected to come from `other_dict.get(k)` in the previous call in the stack when `k` is not there).

Comment: One way to resolve that would be to use a "personal marker" in order to detect missing keys. ```marker = object()```, then the if would be ```if other_dict is not marker: ``` and you have to pass the marker as default value to the get method ```merge_dicts(v, other_dict.get(k, marker))```.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using python 3.5 or later you can simply do:

```
merged_dict = {**base_dict, **other_dict}
```

In case you're using any prior version you can do it with the `update` method:

```
merged_dict = {}
merged_dict.update(base_dict)
merged_dict.update(other_dict)
```

For more information about it you can check [The Idiomatic Way to Merge Dictionaries in Python](http://treyhunner.com/2016/02/how-to-merge-dictionaries-in-python/)

Comment: This doesn't account for nested `dict`s.